# How can I fix my laptop's display; it only shows white screen

Tags: laptop, display

I have an Acer Aspire 5739g laptop.

My laptop's wireless was not working, so I opened the monitor to check the wireless cables and receiver. I pulled the monitor just a bit towards myself to see the cables on the backside of it. I decided that the wireless cables had no problem and closed the monitor. I then started my laptop again. All I see is white screen, no color or anything.

An external monitor works, but it only starts displaying after Windows user login.

What can be the reason of this problem? More importantly, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does your computer boot to windows (i mean do you hear windows star sound)? Do you get outout witha VGA cable to an external monitor? If these work, then you just need to replace the screen cable, otherwise it may be a gpu problem, and you may need to reflow the gpu.

Answer (score 6):

Well it sounds like you un-seated the cable that send the picture to to the monitor. The reason you are only getting a white screen is that the back light is on but there is no data coming through to display.

The cable usually is a ribbon that fits into a slot. The slot then locks by pushing down on the cable and that makes the connection. It is easy to pull this cable out of the slot slightly (or all the way) and this will cause the problem that you are experiencing.

I'm not sure of your exact model but the cable and connection looks something like this:

[image: pic]

As for fixing your wireless, you usually don't need to do anything to the laptops display. You should be able to remove the bottom cover and access the wireless card from there. The antenna are the black and white wires that are coming off the wireless card.

You can check those connections as well as, in most cases, remove the card and replace it with one that works. This should be a picture of your model or similar, you can see where the wireless card is located:

[image: pic]

Comment: But I've tried to pull out then pull in again that cable. That doesn't work. I tried pull out and in again for both cables on monitor and on mainboard

Comment: "I pulled the monitor just a bit towards myself to see the cables on the backside of it." - Did you bend the screen portion or the plastic portion of the case? I'm thinking that if it is not the cables being out of place then maybe you caused damage to the screen. - I have replaced screens on laptops by swapping out a screen from a laptop that i know is working... this may be what you have to do.

Comment: I'm not sure if i bended it,I'm gonna disamble the monitor again tomorrow hope this time it works :/

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like, 1 of the following has happened:

- Video cable  has become loose on either the motherboard or the screen
- Internals of the video cable have been damaged - this usually happens
  where the cable is routed from the base of the laptop to the screen. 
  Very gently squeeze the cable around this section to see if you get
  any picture display on the screen.
- Lastly, it's possible that the screen has become damaged in which
  you will need to replace it.

Luckily you are getting external display so HDD/Ram/Motherboard can be ruled out.

Comment: I've tried to squeeze the cable but that doesn't work and tried plug out then plug in both cables on motherboard and on screen, that doesnt work either

Comment: Ok. Looks like you may need to replace the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Acer Aspire 1410 and got a white screen on startup which faded to black. I left the battery to run down then charged it again. It was fine on startup. I called in for advice and was told it was a buildup of static on the hard drive and if it happened again I was told to remove the battery, press and hold the power button for 15 seconds (to drain the static), then replace the battery and startup as normal.